# Text decoration underline is overriding the test for text block

Tags: wpf, textblock, underline, text-decorations

I am using a text block, for which an underline is added when that text block is hovered. Everything is working well but for some alphabet like y,j the underline is not properly displayed.

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding UserName}" FontSize="16" FontWeight="Bold" VerticalAlignment="Top"
                                                             Cursor="Hand" Grid.Column="0" MouseEnter="OnFocus_UserName" />

 private void OnFocus_UserName(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        ((TextBlock) sender).TextDecorations = TextDecorations.Underline;
    }
```

The output is as following:

[image]:

How to display the underline below the anchor of `y`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the offset of the underline with the following:

```
 <TextBlock Text="reddy" FontSize="16" FontWeight="Bold" VerticalAlignment="Top"
               Grid.Row="2">
        <TextBlock.TextDecorations>
            <TextDecoration PenOffset="3" Location="Underline" />
        </TextBlock.TextDecorations>
    </TextBlock>
```

The penoffset determines how much the offset should be.

[Documentation for the PenOffset Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.textdecoration.penoffset?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8#System_Windows_TextDecoration_PenOffset)